# How to check wordpress php file that does not load correct content?

Tags: php, wordpress

In WordPress, I am trying to use two different themes (Modernist and Tanzaku) for different pages.  I am using Modernist as my base theme, and would like one page to be styled/formated with Tanzaku and returning blog entries with a specified category.

Therefore, I did the following:

1. Updated the functions.php of Modernist with the functions.php file of Tanzaku.
2. Created contest.php file and put the index.php file of Tanzaku, and made some edits.

   - removed  and inserted header
   - took out footer and replace with
3. Added a new page "Contest" under Pages, updated Template under Page Attributes and set it to the contest.php file I created before this step.

However, my php page only loads this?

```
// [grid column setting] $col_w = 290;
// width of grid column $gap_w = 35; 
// padding + margin-right (15+15+5) $max_col = 2; 
// max column size (style div.x1 ~ xN) 
// * additional info * 
// check also "style.css" and "header.php" if you change $col_w and $gap_w. 
// - style.css: 
// div.x1 ~ xN 
// div.grid-item 
// div.single-item 
// ... and maybe #sidebar2 li.widget. 
// - header.php: 
// gridDefWidth in javascript code. 
// // if you want to show small images in main page always, set $max_col = 1. 
// [grid image link setting] $flg_img_forcelink = true; 
// add/overwrite a link which links to a single post (permalink). $flg_img_extract = false; 
// in single post page, extract thumbnail link to an original image. $flg_obj_fit = 'large-fit'; 
// none | small-fit | large-fit ... how to fit size of object tag.
// * additional info * 
// if you use image popup utility (like Lightbox) on main index, set $flg_img_forcelink = false;
```

I have tested both themes by themselves and they work.  For the Tanzaku template, I do have to disable the front.php that I use for the base theme of Modernist.

I have checked apache logs, but there are no errors.  How else can I check for errors of a page that loads, but does not return the results I want it to?

Comment: You're literally getting all that commented code as output from the server? That means you've got an extra `?>` somewhere that's "turning off" PHP, allow the code to leak out.

Comment: Is there an easy way to find this extra ?>

Comment: Download Eclipse Helios for php, and it will show you were your missing tags are. Or you can just use the old way using your eyes : )

Comment: Use any text editor with syntax highlight. My personal favorite is SciTE.

Comment: @Marc B found it.  @OldWest the eyes work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took out extra "?>".  Thanks Marc B!  Wanted to close this question so answered it.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus I needed to wait 20 hours so I can click the checkmark.